# Warning: Encountered two children with the same key, `0`

Tags: arrays, reactjs, html-table, key, mapping

I'm trying to map over an array, and display what I want in table items. It was asking me for a unique key, so I chose the following code because I used it in another component. I'm curious why it's not working here.

```
renderData() {
   const { aminos } = this.props.aminos;
    return aminos.map((micro, i) => {
       return (
        <Table>
          <tbody>
             <tr>
              <th scope="row">1</th>
              <th key={i}>{micro.name}</th>
             </tr>
             <tr>
                <td key={i}>{micro.serum.current}</td>
                <td key={i}>{micro.serum.prev}</td>
                <td key={i}>{micro.serum.ref}</td>
             </tr>
           </tbody>
         </Table>
       )
   }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key should be placed on the outer most component.

```
return aminos.map((micro, i) => {
   return (
    <Table key={i}>
      <tbody>
         <tr>
          <th scope="row">1</th>
          <th >{micro.name}</th>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>{micro.serum.current}</td>
            <td>{micro.serum.prev}</td>
            <td>{micro.serum.ref}</td>
         </tr>
       </tbody>
     </Table>
   )
}
```

Although this map will display multiple tables nor sure this is your desired effect. Also using the index as keys is not a good idea you should use some sort of unique id like a primary key from your Database.

Comment: a little background on why not to use index as key https://medium.com/@robinpokorny/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern-e0349aece318

Comment: @bigjohnjr mind marking it as a correct answer greatly appreciate it.